# Difference between torch.Tensor([1,2,3]) and torch.tensor([1,2,3])?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, torch, pytorch-lightning

I want to understand what is the significance of each function `torch.Tensor([1,2,3])` and `torch.tensor([1,2,3])`.

The one difference I found is `torch.Tensor()` creates tensors with **int64** dtype and `torch.tensor()` creates **float32** dtype by default. Is there any other significant difference between both?

Are there any other differences between both apart from what I have mentioned above, Also, when and where to use which one?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactely the other way around :)

- `torch.Tensor()` returns a tensor that can hold 32-bit floating-point numbers as it is an alias for `torch.FloatTensor`.
- `torch.tensor(X)` (with only integers in `X`) returns a 64-bit integer tensor by default as `torch.tensor()` infers the data type automatically.

But the initialization phase is really the only difference between the options. As [`torch.tensor()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html) is a wrapper function to create a `Tensor` with pre-existing data. It is sometimes recommended to use `torch.tensor()` as it offers some possibilities to specify e.g. the data type by setting the `dtype` argument. On the other hand, to create a Tensor *without* data, you would need to use `torch.Tensor()`. Either way, in both cases you end up with a `torch.Tensor`.

```py
print(torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3]).dtype)  # torch.float32
print(torch.FloatTensor([1, 2, 3]).dtype)  # torch.float32
print(torch.tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=torch.float32).dtype)  # torch.float32
print(torch.equal(torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3]), torch.FloatTensor([1, 2, 3])))  # True
print(torch.equal(torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3]), torch.tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=torch.float32)))  # True

print(torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]).dtype)  # torch.int64
print(torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 3]).dtype)  # torch.int64
print(torch.equal(torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]), torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 3])))  # True

print(torch.Tensor())  # tensor([])
print(torch.tensor())  # throws an error
```